# Angular class property not updating

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which passes a function down to a child component. when something is clicked in the child it calls the function in the parent to update the parent components class properties. I am a little new to Angular so I'm not sure if this is the preferred way or not but regardless, the class properties are not being updated even though the value is being passed into the onVideoSelect function. Am I doing something wrong here? please note I am using Angular 9 from a cdn in the browser so there is no "import" for component. The import for YoutubeService is also unique because a path is not required in the editor I am using.

component:

```
const { Component } = ng.core;

import YoutubeService from 'YoutubeService.ts';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class='App ui container'>
    <h1>AngularTube</h1>
    <search-bar (submitted)="onSearch($event)"></search-bar>
    <div [ngStyle]="{'margin-top': '15px'}">
      <video-detail [video]="selectedVideo"></video-detail>
      <video-list [videos]="videos" [onVideoSelect]="onVideoSelect" ></video-list> 
    <div>  
  </div>
`
})     
// 
export default class AppComponent {
  videos = [];
  selectedVideo = null;

  constructor(private youtube: YoutubeService) { }

  // this works
  onSearch(searchTerm: string) {
    this.youtube.search(searchTerm).subscribe((response) => {
      this.videos = [...response.items];
      this.selectedVideo = {...response.items[0]};
    });
  }

  // this does not update the class property selectedVideo
  onVideoSelect(video: object) {
    this.selectedVideo = {...video};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you to avoid passing callbacks to the component. Instead of doing this, Angular provides you an API to handle events from your components using the `@Output` decorator.

In your case, you have lost your execution context.
Learn, how `this` works inside the callbacks.

And if you still need the callback there, try to bind context in your constructor function `this.onVideoSelect = this.onVideoSelect.bind(this);`

Comment: Ahhhh right, thanks! I will try emitting an event with Output!